# Como fazer um select começando por uma determinada linha

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Como eu faço para obter um `Select` começando por exemplo da segunda linha da minha tabela?

Sei que utilizando o `ASC limit 1,1` posso escolher a segunda linha, mas como começar a partir dela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode colocar o segundo **valor** do `LIMIT` como maior do que a tabela pode chegar ou **valor** que pensar ser adequado.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ASC LIMIT 1,999999999999999999
```

Comment: Engenhoso! Mas deve funcionar mesmo... :)